# Applescript code to refresh a single iTunes podcast

Tags: applescript, itunes

I prefer to refresh my iTunes podcasts at times I control, so usually I right-click on the one I want to refresh, and choose Refresh Podcast.  But sometimes I mistakenly select another menu item, and that's a real PITA.  So I'd like to have an applescript which will only refresh a single podcast.  I plan to hard-code the podcast into the script -- there's only one that I do near-daily, and the others can be done as and when I feel like it, with right-click.  If I mess them up it's less of a PITA than with the main one.

The iTunes dictionary has `updatePodcast` and `updateAllPodcasts` -- clearly the former is the one I need to use (I don't want to have them all updated every time).  But I can't figure out how to specify the podcast!  The dictionary doesn't have a `podcast` class or anything similar, and `item` offers no obvious guidance either.

I've tried:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    updatePodcast NameOfPodcast
end tell
```

Where `NameOfPodcast` is replaced by the exact string (AFAIK) that is in the iTunes podcast listing.  Applescript tells me:

```
error "iTunes got an error: NameOfPodcast doesn’t understand the “updatePodcast” message." number -1708 from NameOfPodcast
```

Does anyone know how to get iTunes to refresh a **single** podcast from within applescript?

**Edit:**
Thanks to @user3439894 and @wp78de but referring to a track doesn't work.  AS complains that the track doesn't understand the `updatePodcast` message.  If I try to get a list of albums instead (`every album of playlist "Podcasts" whose name is album_name`), I get told that `album` is a property whereas it wants a class name.

Comment: Here is an example I found doing a Google search for _applescript itunes updatePodcast_: https://gist.github.com/nandff/314081 It looks like it should work but I cannot test it. I'd imagine you can also change `first track` of `updatePodcast (first track of playlist "Podcasts" whose album is album_name)` to: `every track ...`

Comment: See edit to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set allTracks to every track of playlist "Podcasts" whose album is "podcast_name"
    repeat with singleTrack in allTracks
        updatePodcast singleTrack
    end repeat
end tell
```

Or try

```
tell application "iTunes"
    updatePodcast (first track of playlist "Podcasts" whose album is "XY Podcast")
end tell
```

Comment: sigh, I guess it's an iTunes version issue then...thanks anyway!